# How to render 8bit indexed bitmap using GDI?

Tags: windows, qt, gdi+, gdi, freetype

I'm trying to render a freetype's glyph to a window using windows GDI. It seems the bitmap generated by freetype is 8bit index bitmap or something, because in its official tutorial example4.cpp, it use Qt to render the glyph as follows:

```
error = FT_Render_Glyph(m_face->glyph,
                    FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL);

            QImage glyphImage(m_face->glyph->bitmap.buffer,
                m_face->glyph->bitmap.width,
                m_face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
                m_face->glyph->bitmap.pitch,
                QImage::Format_Indexed8);

            /*painter.translate(m_glyphRect.x(),
                m_glyphRect.y());*/

            QVector<QRgb> colorTable;
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
                colorTable << qRgba(0, 0, 0, i);
            glyphImage.setColorTable(colorTable);

            painter.drawImage(QPoint(0, 0),
                glyphImage);
```

So I try to render it using gdi as follows:

```
BITMAPINFO* pBmi = (BITMAPINFO*)malloc(sizeof(BITMAPINFO) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * 255);
            BITMAPINFOHEADER &bmh = pBmi->bmiHeader;
            bmh.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
            bmh.biBitCount = 8;
            bmh.biCompression = BI_RGB;
            bmh.biPlanes = 1;
            RGBQUAD* palette = &pBmi->bmiColors[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
                RGBQUAD rgb = {0};
                palette[i] = rgb;
            }

            //assert(pBm->bitmap);
            bmh.biWidth = pBm->bitmap.width;
            bmh.biHeight =  - pBm->bitmap.rows;
            StretchDIBits(hdc, 200, 200, pBm->bitmap.width, pBm->bitmap.rows, 0, 0, pBm->bitmap.width, pBm->bitmap.rows, pBm->bitmap.buffer, 
                pBmi, DIB_PAL_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
```

Then I try to use GDI+ to render, but failed too.

```
error = FT_Render_Glyph(m_face->glyph, FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL);
            Bitmap bitmap(pBm->bitmap.width, pBm->bitmap.rows, pBm->bitmap.pitch, PixelFormat8bppIndexed, pBm->bitmap.buffer);
            //Bitmap bitmap(pBm->bitmap.width, pBm->bitmap.rows, 64, PixelFormat8bppIndexed, pBm->bitmap.buffer);
            ColorPalette* pal = (ColorPalette*)malloc(sizeof(ColorPalette) + 255 * sizeof(ARGB));
            pal->Flags = PaletteFlagsGrayScale;
            pal->Count = 256;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
                pal->Entries[i] = Color::MakeARGB(i, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            bitmap.SetPalette(pal);
            Graphics graphics(hdc);
            graphics.DrawImage(&bitmap, 100, 100);
```

Could you please tell me, how to render 8bit per pixel indexed bitmap in Windows using GDI/GDI+.
Thanks.

Comment: Q: Where's your color map?  http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Windows__Programming/MFC/Q_10104503.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Qt example you give creates a color palette that's all black, with the transparency varying with the intensity. The palette you're using with GDI is all black, period. You need to vary the color.

Answer (score 3):

Just as a note here:

```
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        assert(Draw());

        FT_GlyphSlot &pBm = m_face->glyph;

        //output by console
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < pBm->bitmap.rows; j++) {
                printf("\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < pBm->bitmap.width; i++) 
                    printf("%2x", pBm->bitmap.buffer[j * pBm->bitmap.width + i]);
            }
        }

        //output by gdi+
        {
            Bitmap *pBitmap = NULL;
            LPBYTE pBuffer = NULL;      
            int stride = (pBm->bitmap.pitch + 3) / 4 * 4;
            if (stride != pBm->bitmap.pitch)
            {
                pBuffer = new BYTE[stride * pBm->bitmap.rows];
                memset(pBuffer, 0, stride * pBm->bitmap.rows);
                for (int i = 0; i < pBm->bitmap.rows; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < pBm->bitmap.width; j++)
                        pBuffer[i * stride + j] = pBm->bitmap.buffer[i * pBm->bitmap.width + j];
            } else
            {
                pBuffer = pBm->bitmap.buffer;
            }
            pBitmap = new Bitmap(pBm->bitmap.width, pBm->bitmap.rows, stride, PixelFormat8bppIndexed, pBuffer);
            ColorPalette *pPalette = (ColorPalette*)malloc(sizeof(ColorPalette) + 255 * sizeof(ARGB));
            pPalette->Count = 256;
            pPalette->Flags = PaletteFlagsGrayScale;
            ARGB* pColor = &pPalette->Entries[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
                pColor[i] = Color::MakeARGB(i, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
            assert(pBitmap->GetLastStatus() == Ok);
            pBitmap->SetPalette(pPalette);
            assert(pBitmap->GetLastStatus() == Ok);
            Graphics graphics(hdc);
            graphics.DrawImage(pBitmap, 300, 300);

            free(pPalette);
            delete pBitmap;

            //draw with gdi
            {
                BITMAPINFO* pBmi = (BITMAPINFO*)malloc(sizeof(BITMAPINFO) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * 255);
                memset(pBmi, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
                BITMAPINFOHEADER &bmh = pBmi->bmiHeader;
                bmh.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
                bmh.biBitCount = 8;
                bmh.biCompression = BI_RGB;
                bmh.biPlanes = 1;
                RGBQUAD* palette = &pBmi->bmiColors[0];
                for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) 
                {
                    RGBQUAD rgb = {0};
                    rgb.rgbRed =  ~i;
                    rgb.rgbGreen =  ~i;
                    rgb.rgbBlue =  ~i;
                    palette[i] = rgb;
                }
                bmh.biWidth = stride;
                bmh.biHeight =  - pBm->bitmap.rows;
                StretchDIBits(hdc, 200, 200, stride, pBm->bitmap.rows, 0, 0, stride, pBm->bitmap.rows, pBuffer, 
                    pBmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);

                if (pBmi)
                    free(pBmi);

                if (pBuffer != pBm->bitmap.buffer)
                    delete [] pBuffer;

                /*bmh.biWidth = pBm->bitmap.width;
                bmh.biHeight =  - pBm->bitmap.rows;
                StretchDIBits(hdc, 200, 200, pBm->bitmap.width, pBm->bitmap.rows, 0, 0, pBm->bitmap.width, pBm->bitmap.rows, pBm->bitmap.buffer, 
                    pBmi, DIB_PAL_COLORS, SRCCOPY);*/
            }

        }
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

Two points:
1) as Mark Randsom and paulsm4 said color palette is mandantory.
2) align by 4.

Comment: Most of the time the stride is aligned by 4 just because the width is a multiple of 4. It's good to enforce it though.

Comment: @MarkRansom: if here i do not enforce, the result will be incorrect.